# duplicated constructor and method functionality in c++

Tags: c++

Maybe the question is simple, but what is the best practices for doing something like this, assume there is a class Data, that has to read some information from a text file. If one needs to have both of the following options with equal behaviour:

```
Data my_data;
my_data.load("file.txt");
```

and

```
Data my_data("file.txt");
```

how to realise such functionality without duplicating of code?

Thanks.

Comment: Just call the load method in the constructor

Comment: It depends on what you're working with. I'm going to assume that `Data` is useless if you haven't loaded something yet because that is the most common scenario. In that case it is safer to not provide a default constructor, as to catch uninitialized use errors during compilation. Otherwise, the provided answers of the constructor calling load are what you need.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It works, though I don't understand why, if load is defined and implemented after the constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid code duplication by reusing the `load` member function in the constructor:

```
Data() { // Provide a default constructor
}
Data(const std::string& fileName) {
    load(fileName);
}
void load(const std::string& fileName) {
    ... // Load the file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare 2 constructors (it's called overloading).

```
Data()
{
}
```

and

```
Data(string fileName)
{
    load(fileName);
}
```

and than you can define just once the load function.